# web.xml configuration for JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

[image]

This is the structure of the JSP app on eclipse.Once I run it on eclipse using tomcat server(localhost:8090/index4.html) it works.On the index page i have to add details,this details are uploaded via the servlet as you can see above `Java Resources->src->FileUPloadDBServlet`(Also I am not sure if it uses this or it uses `WEB-INF->src->FileUploadServlet` below.)
In my `index4.html` the action is `action=uploadServlet`(no address given for it).This everything works on using eclipse.
But once I put the QMS folder(not WAR) from eclipse worskspace to tomcat ROOT,the index4.html works but the following action,i.e uploadServlet doesnt work(here I use the address localhost:8090/WebContent/index4.html)I dont have a web.xml.
Is that creating a problem?
Please provide me help.

Comment: Without `web.xml` how it will redirect to your Servlet?

Comment: Thats what i just noticed in eclipse.In `Deployment desciptor:QMS` it says web.xml file is missing.But then how does it work on eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse has already web.xml

Comment: where will i find it?cause I cant see it

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your project folder or .war file in the

> webapps folder of Tomcat directly not in ROOT folder under webapps.

Try to follow directory structure as follows[image]

**Photo Courtesy** http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/steps-to-create-servlet-using-tomcat-server.php (Here you can also find more details on Servlet and JSP, as well as project structure)

Where you have your web.xml put into the WEB-INF folder under your application folder.
For java files you don't need the source files, the classes folder will have all the source  folder (src) files compiled and ready to execute.

The lib will contain all the .jar files you need for your application to run.

> Make sure you put web.xml file at proper place, because without it, application will not be able to run. Because as they say web.xml is Heart of the application.

Answer (score -1):

Let me explain you the problem.

When we configure a dynamic java project to run on eclipse the server takes the just the stuff from webcontent folder and deploy it the wbcontent folder contains web.xml file which defines the url descriptor for servlet.

now when you copy the whole folder the server can not find the web.xml file which is a descriptor where it expects the file to be.

hope its clear comment for clarification

Comment: Thanks,I got the idea of web.xml...but I ran into a problem.I put the web.xml and had a <welcome> page tag for it,it worked on eclipse but once I exported as WAR and threw it in the tomcat ROOT,the index page wasnt displayed?the address i used was localhost:8089/QMS

Comment: Try restarting the server(tomcat server through shutdown and startup files in bin folder). I think you are also using the wrong port it should be 8080

Comment: I changed the port in the conf/server.xml to 8089

Comment: was this port changed in eclipse or the server.xml file of actual apache installation because both maintain diferent server.xml file